# currently i'm building a simple lottery contract with help of react but getting error .default.methods.manager is not a function in react

Tags: reactjs, solidity, web3js

Currently, I'm building a simple lottery contract with the help of `react.js`. this is my `app.js` file in `react.js` with `web3`, lottery contract is working well on remix can't find an error in this file.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import web3 from './web3';
import lottery from './lottery';

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = { manager: '' };
}

async componentDidMount() {
const manager = await lottery.methods.manager().call();

this.setState({ manager });
}

render(){
return (
<div>
  <h2> Lottery contract</h2>
  <p>this contract if managed by {this.state.manager}</p>
</div>
      
);
}

}

export default App;
```

## lottery.js

```
import web3 from './web3';

const address = '0xBEFF762b1A78D1263b43e72630843D093B5c36d4';

const abi = [
    {"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newMessage","type":"string"}],"name":"setMessage","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"message","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"initialMessage","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}];

export default new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

[image]

Comment: The code from the module `'./lottery'` would be needed to understand the problem here

Answer (score 0):

Your ABI array does not seem to have a function called `manager` and possibly so the error `default.methods.manager is not a function` is thrown.

The only functions in your ABI array are `setMessage` and `message`.